# Can mtrace be successfully run with valgrind?

Tags: c, valgrind, mtrace

I have a program which does 5 mallocs and 3 frees. I call mtrace() at the start and muntrace() at the end. mtrace will report the missing frees if I run the program normally. If I do:

```
valgrind -v --log-file=val.log --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes my_program
```

valgrind will report the missing frees but mtrace will not.

So I guess you can't use them both together - valgrind will override mtrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I guess you can't use them both together

Correct.

> valgrind will override mtrace?

I don't believe Valgrind overrides `mtrace`, but it *does* override `malloc` and `free`, so `mtrace` simply never sees either `malloc` of `free`.